# Get Contacts and Groups from Exchange Online Default Global Address List folder Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to get contacts and groups from Exchange Online Default Global Address List folder using Microsoft Graph API.

I want to fectch all the data of this folder

[image]

I have tried using contacts api but it does not return groups and some contact are also missing
[image]

I have also tried using prople api but it does return contacts and groups but it still does not match with Default Global Address List contents
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the following query.
**`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people`**

Auth url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
Token url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token`
&Client ID : xxx
&Client Secret
Scope =`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

With above I got the access token with following permissions.

[image]

For the below query make sure to have `People.Read.All, Contacts.ReadWrite ,Directory .ReadWrite.All` application and delegated permissions

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people
```

Headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer Token
ConsistencyLevel : eventual
Content-type: application/json
```

I could  get the groups from the above query

[image]

> **Note** that by default, system-related mailboxes like arbitration
> mailboxes and public folder mailboxes are hidden from address lists.

see ***[Default Global Address Lis (GAL) |  Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/address-books/address-lists/address-lists)***   which says

> By default, the Address List role isn't assigned to any role groups in
> Exchange Online. To use any cmdlets or features that require the
> Address List role, you need to add the role to a role group. For more
> information, see Modify role groups.

Also checked `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$select=displayname, resourceBehaviorOptions`

[image]

**Reference** : [Modify role Groups | microsoft learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/permissions-exo/role-groups#modify-role-groups)

Comment: Thanks, @kavyaS for the detailed answer. I have tried with the permissions you have suggested but the problem is using people API I am not getting exact same list of contacts and groups that are there in the Global Address List. Can you please suggest what I can do to get the same list of contacts and groups?